# Communications link failure during rollback Error, using Quartz by springframework

Tags: mysql, quartz-scheduler, spring-scheduled

Getting exception Communications link failure during rollback(), We are using **quartz 2.2.1** with org.springframework.scheduling.**quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean**

Please find exception 
org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore Couldn't rollback jdbc connection. Communications link failure during rollback(). Transaction resolution unknown.
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Communications link failure during rollback(). Transaction resolution unknown.

When wait_timeout 600 sec getting these exception after 30min to 1hours. 
When I am using default wait_timeout 28800 sec so getting this exception after 8 to 10 hours.

Tried **autoReconnect=true** and stillthe issue persist.

Comment: how long your job stay idle? More specifically, how long time betweene two execution of your scheduled jobs?

Comment: currently we have 5 jobs and running each 3 min and all are in different mins

Comment: check if autocommit is enabled in your mysql server. if so turn it out, because since autocommit is on the DBMs commit each statement, and so your scheduler cannot do any rollabck.

Comment: No it's not working.  
`org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_ 
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true 
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = myDs org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.URL = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/quartzd org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.validationQuery = select 1 org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.testConnectionOnCheckout=true`

Comment: I mean autocommit on MYSQL server https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html

Comment: Yes tried autocommit too

`show variables like 'autocommit'` now showing **OFF**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155935/discussion-between-koushik-rout-and-roberto-benazzato).